# Handle Exceptions with Try Catch

Tags: java, validation, exception, input, try-catch

I'm new at java and I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong with my coding. every time I enter a letter it crashes? as shown below.

Read in a mark

y

Error plz enter a number

Enter the next student mark

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at histogram.Histogram.main(Histogram.java:95)

 bC:\Users\Chevon\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
     BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

**This is my code:**

```
    int cat1 = 0;// Category 1
    int cat2 = 0;// Category 2
    int cat3 = 0;//Category 3
    int cat4 = 0;//Category 4
    int mark = 0;// Total marks that the user enters
    int counter = 0;
    double Average = 0;
    int Total_mark = 0;
    int pass=0;
    int highest = 0;
    int lowest = 101;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Read in a mark");
     try{
         mark= input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("The number you enter is "+mark);
     }catch(InputMismatchException e){
         System.out.println("Error plz enter a number");

     }
     while(mark<0){
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer"); 
        mark = input.nextInt();
    }
```

**I expected it to be like this**

Read in mark

y

Error plz enter a number

Enter next student mark

4

Comment: After you say "read in mark", what do you think `nextInt()` does?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `catch` works only the for the first user input. 
You should add another `catch` to handle the `InputMismatchException`  in the next user inputs. Otherwise, the exception goes up and you leave the method if the input is not a number.

Try that :

```
 try{
     mark= input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("The number you enter is "+mark);
 }
 catch(InputMismatchException e){
     System.out.println("Error plz enter a number");
 }

 while(mark<0){
    try{
      System.out.println("Enter a positive integer"); 
      mark = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Error plz enter a number");
    } 

}
```